# Filter by Datetime

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-views

I need to filter with a Datetime field, but I need that to take the hour to, not just the date, like is doing it now, I't doesn't count the time just the date.

view.py

```
 @login_required(login_url='/InicieSesion')
    def adendum_Detalle(request, credencial, fecha):
    print 'subsecuente detalle'
    date_for_search = datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha, '%Y%m%d').date()
    print date_for_search
    formulario =   get_object_or_404(adendum,adendum_credencial=credencial,adendum_fecha=date_for_search)
    return render(request, 'adedetalle.html', {'formulario': formulario})
```

I was trying to add the date here  (fecha, '%Y%m%d') to convert it to string, but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you please rephrase what you're looking to do? I'm not sure what you mean by `but I need that to take the hour to, not just the date`. Are you saying you need to filter by date and hour, by just hour, or what? And when you mean filter, do you really mean Django's `.filter` for a queryset to return multiple objects, or `.get` like you used here to get a single object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter on specific parts of the datetime in Django using `datetimefield__year`, `datetimefield__day`, etc.

If you are trying to filter by both date and hour, you can do:

```
formulario =   get_object_or_404(adendum,adendum_credencial=credencial,
    adendum_fecha__year=date_for_search.year, 
    adendum_fecha__month=date_for_search.month, 
    adendum_fecha__day=date_for_search.day,
    adendum_fecha__hour=1)
```

I feel like there may be a better way to do this, probably by building a datetime object based on the date_for_search you have combined with the hour you're looking for, but you'd have to ignore the minutes/seconds in that case and I can't say I'm quite sure on how to do that. This should get you started, though!